# What would happen if cookies are disabled on the system?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am new in development.  Although I have some idea about the working process of sessions and cookies, I have one doubt in my mind: what would happen if cookies are disabled on the system?  How session would uniquely identify the user, etc.?

Comment: disable it and then try accessing gmail, facebook etc and see what happens

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty could you describe it properly??

Comment: checkout you have some answers already for this.

Comment: Unless you have some other form of transmitting the Session ID (using GET/POST variables for example): A new session will be started, as if 2 completely different users were visiting the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting question.

Although PHP sessions were invented initially to work with cookies disabled, this feature was proven insecure and become somewhat frowned upon nowadays.

However, this feature still works - PHP can rewrite all local links adding session id to them and thus make it transferred from page to page.

Yet it's still insecure, as unsuspecting user may send a hyperlink to a friend, and session id as well - making friend logged in.

> How session would uniquely identify the user, etc.?

The idea of a session is not to identify the user but **to transfer a session id between separate requests.** So, as long as you can manage to do so - you can keep the session. Say, in a modern web-application that is using AJAX all the way, one can do without cookies all right, yet keep application pretty  secure - just by means of transferring session id strictly via AJAX calls, not showing it in the address bar.

Comment: And this is supposed to be an answer?

Comment: How would sessions work without cookies?  How would PHP know which session is yours?

Comment: Sure. An answer that have to be posted before question got closed by hasty citizens %)

Comment: ASP.Net can also be configured to support cookieless sessions.

Comment: (A link the PHP feature documentation/configuration sees prudent.)

Answer (score 2):

Some server-side frameworks can use URL rewriting to maintain session state in the absence of cookies.  For such frameworks, sessions can still be maintained though information could not be persisted once the user leaves (e.g. you could not save the username to pre-populate a login field when the user checks "remember me").

For systems that rely on cookies, no session would be possible.

Many websites offer some capability when the user is not logged in (for example, you can browse Stack Overflow but not post).

Comment: How does URL rewriting maintain session state?  Is the session stored in the URL string?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Exactly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It depends. Server-side sessions can still be used if the appropriate "session/state" token is encoded in the resource access (that is, the entire state need not be encoded). On a system that relies heavily on postbacks (ASP.NET WebForms - I'm looking at you) as opposed to redirects, then a heavyweight-state might even be persisted in that manner through form data.

Comment: That's what I meant.  Typically a session token will be written into the URL, which the server uses as a key to look up any information associated with that session in a server-side data structure.